# How can I tell Watir where specifically within a table cell to double click?

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm working with a table that has in-line editing.  To make a cell editable, you double click on it.

While I know exactly how to double-click on a cell, some of the cells I need to do this on have hyperlinks in them.

This means that sometimes when Watir tries to double-click on the cell, it instead accidentally clicks on the hyperlink, navigating to an entirely new page.

How do I tell it to click the empty space in the cell rather than the hyperlink?

Comment: Is this for watir-classic or watir-webdriver?

Comment: watir-webdriver.  thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Watir-webdriver's Element#double_click will always click the middle of the element. If you need to click somewhere else, you will need to use the underlying selenium-webdriver `move_to` action builder code.

Given the html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td onclick="javascript:document.title = 'New title';">
                    <a href="http://www.google.ca">hi</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Using double-click for the cell, clicks the link (since is in the middle of the cell):

```
el = browser.td
el.double_click
browser.title
#=> "Google"
```

However, we can use the underlying selenium-webdriver code to move the mouse to somewhere in the cell that is not the middle (ie where the link is). The following moves the mouse to the top left corner of the cell:

```
el = browser.td
el.driver.action.move_to(el.wd, 0, 0).double_click.perform
browser.title
#=> "New title"
```

Note that for the [`move_to` method](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/ActionBuilder.html#move_to-instance_method), the second parameter is how far to move right from the top left corner and the third parameter is how far to move down from the top left corner.